# Weird crash at asigning a glm::vec3 constant reference to another glm::vec3

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm having a ModelMatrix class in which i have a glm::vec3 defined as

```
glm::vec3 *position = nullptr;
```

Then i got a setter method

```
void ModelMatrix::SetPosition(const glm::vec3 &position)
{
    delete this->position;

    *this->position = position;
}
```

at asigning the constant reference the problem occurs.

It goes inside this method

```
template <typename T, precision P>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tvec3<T, P>& tvec3<T, P>::operator= (tvec3<T, P> const & v)
{
    this->x = v.x;
    this->y = v.y;
    this->z = v.z;
    return *this;
}
```

And then just crashes on the first line of the method.

This is a snippet from the call stack.

```
glm::detail::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0>::operator= at type_vec3.inl:189 0x404f78   
core3d::ModelMatrix::SetPosition() at ModelMatrix.cpp:58 0x405bc3   
core3d::ModelMatrix::ModelMatrix() at ModelMatrix.cpp:7 0x40582b
```

I don't have any error message.
What is causing this error?

Comment: s/`*this->position = position;`/`*(this->position) = position;`/

Comment: `->` has a higher precedence than `*` (indirection), so it is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The much better approach here is to not use a pointer at all. `glm::vec3` is a fixed size type that probably uses 12 or 16 bytes. I see absolutely no need to use a separate dynamic allocation for it.

So where you currently declare your class member as:

```
glm::vec3 *position;
```

simply change this to:

```
glm::vec3 position;
```

Then remove all the `new`/`delete` calls you currently have for the class member. The setter method then becomes:

```
void ModelMatrix::SetPosition(const glm::vec3 &position)
{
    this->position = position;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are deferencing memory which you've now deallocated:

```
delete this->position;
*this->position = position;
```

I don't know why you are bothering to delete it, as I don't think the glm::vec3 destructor actually does anything important, so you can just do:

```
*this->position = position;
```

Comment: So if i dont delete it what happens to the old object?

Comment: The old object is still there, you just replaced its x, y, z values

Comment: Re: your comments on your answer to the now-deleted question. Please [be nice.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) You're entitled to your opinions, but there's no need for the language.

Comment: SO achieved and is maintaining its current position by *enforcing the rules* on what is and isn't on-topic. If you don't like the rules, take it to Meta, but please don't run your mouth.